# How can i do a setter to fix computed propery problem - VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Im trying to fix this error where i cant close the dialog by clicking the X button on the top right, but i can close it by clicking the "Agregar" or "Cancelar" button.

**This is how i sync my Dialog**

```
<el-dialog title="Agregar Persona" :visible.sync="getAgregarPersonaDialog">
```

**And here is my Computed Property**

```
computed: {
getAgregarPersonaDialog() {
      return this.$store.state.agregarPersonaDialog;
    }
}
```

**This is how i change the value of my state**

```
setAgregarPersonaDialogo(state) {
      state.agregarPersonaDialog = !state.agregarPersonaDialog
    },
```

And in my state i have this atribute

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
state: {
  agregarPersonaDialog: false
}
});
```

This is the error i have everytime i click the X button on the dialog

```
Computed property "getAgregarPersonaDialog" was assigned to but it has no setter.
```

[image: scrren]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Vuex, if your need to mutate any data on state arises then you absolutely need an action that calls a mutation to mutate state.

This is the most important use case of Vuex, **to keep track of actions that mutates state**

what you did is absolutely wrong.

To achieve your goal, you need two things.

1. an action
2. a mutation

```
action: {
// The first parameter is an object, so it be destructured
// for simple access
doSomething({ commit }, payload){
// commit a change by calling mutation, second parameter
// is the arguments you passed to your action
 commit('mutateData', payload)
}
},

mutations: {
mutateData(state, payload) {
// You can instead commit the argument
// I.e state.data = payload
  state.agregarPersonaDialog = !state.agregarPersonaDialog;
}
},
```

You can then dispatch your actions in any components

```
methods: {
changeValue(){
this.$store.dispatch('doSomething', 'this is an arg');
// Note I passed an argument just for illustration
// in your case, you don't have to
}
}
```

Now your code should work

Answer (score 0):

```
ti change the state you need 
 1. action
 2. Mutator

example in store.js
state: {
agregarPersonaDialog: false,
},

// value is data what you send from your componet

action: {
changeState(context){
 context.commit('changeValue')
},

mutations: {
changeValue(state) {
  state.agregarPersonaDialog = !state.agregarPersonaDialog;
}
},

---------------------
in your compoent create method

methods: {
changeValue(){
this.$store.dispatch('changeState');
}
}
```

try this!